# why there is a missing stroke on svg polygon

Tags: html, css, svg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="500" height="500">
<polyline style="fill: lime; stroke: green; stroke-width: 3;" points="0,0,273,133,214,42"/>
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

This is my code, may I ask why there is a missing stroke or border on one side of the polygon of the svg, but why this works?

```
<polygon points="200,10 250,190 160,210" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:3" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an extra `0,0` at the end.

```
points="0,0,273,133,214,42,0,0"
```

Comment: Then why this works? <polygon points="200,10 250,190 160,210" style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:3" />

Comment: Because it's `polygon`. You asked a question about `polyline`.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between a `<polygon>` and a `<polyline>` in SVG is that a [polygon](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#PolygonElement) is closed i.e. it has an extra line that connects the last point back to the first point.

You can do this manually with a [polyline](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#PolylineElement) by adding an extra point that is at the same location as the first point of course.